# Smart work/work smart/work remotely

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say: I'm smart working due to covid-19 lockdown.
Or is it more correct to say: I'm working remotely due to covid-19 lockdown.

Comment: “To work from home”, “be a remote worker”, “work remotely”https://hbr.org/2020/03/15-questions-about-remote-work-answered?utm_medium=paidsearch&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=dsa&hideIntromercial=true&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8dDg0rSS6QIVxYGyCh0nvgAJEAAYASAAEgL4Q_D_BwE - https://www.glassdoor.com/blog/companies-that-let-you-work-remotely/

Comment: The trouble with using "smart working" to mean "working remotely" is that it suggests that the work you do in the office _isn't_ smart.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: 'Work smart' is pushing the bounds of grammaticality, certainly acceptable as a punchy slogan but with a questionable flat adverb. I don't think the world's ready for the derived compound verb in all its glory yet, _I'm smart-working_ (though if it's in OED, I'll admit I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, it's not correct to use "smart working".  As well as Edwin's correct observation re pushing the bounds, I have only heard "smart working" to mean "efficient working".  In the sense of "work smarter, not harder".  I.e. rather than just putting in more effort/time, optimise your approach.

If you mean working from home instead of your usual place of work, "working remotely" or "remote working" is indeed correct.

Comment: Hello. Srhino. Answers need to be more substantial than responses in 'comments', including supporting evidence (linked references, or lack of data after sensible searches); answers without supporting evidence come across as (and may be no more than) opinion, and are sometimes inaccurate.